# unescaped column value in xmlforest

Tags: xml, oracle

I have a table column which stores xml chunks like

```
<Text>hello, world</Text></Image id="100">
```

or plain text without tags. How can I generate xml out of tagged column values without escaped symbols.

here is an example of the statement:

```
select xmlelement("Proposal", xmlforest(1 as "ProposalType"
                                   ,to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy') as "CreateDate"
                                   ,'title1' as "Title"
                                   ,'<Text>hello, world</Text></Image id="100">' as "InfoBlock"))
  from dual;
```

and resulting xml looks like this:

```
<Proposal>
    <ProposalType>1</ProposalType>
    <CreateDate>31.10.2012</CreateDate>
    <Title>title1</Title>
   <InfoBlock2>&lt;Text&gt;hello, world&lt;/Text&gt;&lt;/Image id=&quot;100&quot;&gt;</InfoBlock2>
</Proposal>
```

but I need xml like this:

```
<Proposal>
    <ProposalType>1</ProposalType>
    <CreateDate>31.10.2012</CreateDate>
    <Title>title1</Title>
    <InfoBlock2>
        <Text>hello, world</Text><Image id="100"/>
    </InfoBlock2>
</Proposal>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can do:

```
  select xmlelement("Proposal",xmlelement("ProposalType",1)
                              ,xmlelement("CreateDate",to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy'))
                              ,xmlelement("Title",'Title1')
                              ,xmlelement("InfoBlock",xmlelement("Text",'Hello World')
                                                     ,xmlelement("Image",xmlattributes(10 as "Id"))
                                         )
                   )           
  from dual;
```

Result:

```
<Proposal>
    <ProposalType>1</ProposalType>
    <CreateDate>31.10.2012</CreateDate>
    <Title>Title1</Title>
    <InfoBlock>
        <Text>Hello World</Text>
        <Image Id="10"></Image>
    </InfoBlock>
</Proposal>
```

This gives

```
<Image Id="10"></Image>
```

Don't know how to do

```
<Image id="10"/>
```

Comment: If it's really necessary, you can get `<Image Id="10"/>` with something like this: `XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENT( [xml code here] ) INDENT SIZE = 2`.

Comment: your proposal is a static structure, but I need a dynamic, based on the column values (and values may be like 'Hello, world!' or '<Text>Hello, world!</Text>' or '<Text>Hello, world!</Text><Image Id="10">'. In all that cases I need aforementioned xml output)

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> select xmlelement("Proposal",
  2                     xmlforest(1 as "ProposalType",
  3                               to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy') as "CreateDate",
  4                              'title1' as "Title"
  5                              ),
  6                     xmltype('<InfoBlock><Text>hello, world</Text><Image id="100"/></InfoBlock>'))
  7             .extract('/*') -- not needed, just put to pretty-print output.
  8    from dual;

XMLELEMENT(PROPOSAL,XMLFORES
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Proposal>
  <ProposalType>1</ProposalType>
  <CreateDate>01.11.2012</CreateDate>
  <Title>title1</Title>
  <InfoBlock>
    <Text>hello, world</Text>
    <Image id="100"/>
  </InfoBlock>
</Proposal>
```

as you want the string to be dynamic, use xmltype and not xmlforest for that entry. Just make sure the "hello, world" or whatever is properly encoded.